# App OnStartup Error: Access to path 'C:\Users\<userid>\AppData\Local\AppName\VersionFolder\Some.dll' is denied

Tags: c#, wpf, squirrel.windows

I have a desktop application that has a setup.exe built by Squirrel.

The app files get downloaded to the users machine at this location:

`C:\Users\<userid>\AppData\Local\AppName\VersionFolder\`

And a short cut is created on the desktop. For some users, when they run the application, they get the error

> "App OnStartup Error: Access to path C:\Users\\AppData\Local\AppName\VersionFolder\Some.dll is denied."

Not sure what's going on?

It works fine for me and few other users. One of users who get this error has admin rights to their pc. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: @KJSR: Thank you for the edit. My bad on not formatting it before posting.

Comment: Did the setup.exe complete without errors?  You should be able to tell if it completed because all the folder should be in the users folder.

Comment: @jdweng: It did complete without errors.I see all the files in the folder and the shortcut got created as well.

Comment: Is another application required to be installed on PC?  It looks like there is a dependency on another program (may be needs a license).

Comment: @jdweng: No, this application is not dependent on any other applications. It's a stand alone.

Comment: Was the user login when the setup.exe was run (or a different user?).  You would have to go into the files and check the properties to see see what credentials are on the files..

Comment: yes, the user had logged in to the pc using their credentials and when I look at the files in that folder, it shows they have full control.

Comment: You may have an issue with the TLS cedrtificate : https://github.com/micromdm/squirrel/blob/master/README.md  Is it possible the other users that work already had a certificate installed?  There were some issues with Squirrel with updates.  So may be the users that failed were updates and new users worked.

Comment: Is there a brain-dead antivirus program installed on the PC having problems?

Comment: @AlwaysLearning: Not that I know of.

Comment: I think @jdweng might be on to it. Since you mentioned that this user has Administrative rights, it could be an Administrative Token issue. Could they have been using UAC to install the program, such as from a Run-as-Administrator Command Prompt or PowerShell prompt, and are now trying to execute the program without UAC? What happens if they try to start the program with right-click > Run as Administrator?

Comment: Two other things to consider.  1) Many of the Net library methods are just wrappers calling windows dlls.  When you run setup.exe one of the things that is done is the windows dlls get updated which requires Admin.  Now if you run the setup as an Admin the c:\User folder doesn't get installed properly unless you put files in All Users.  If you do not run as admin then the need wndows dlls do not get update.

Comment: 2) The hardware platforms may not be the same.  So if the PC have different CODEC on the machines the code may work on one PC and not another.  So missing files could be due to different hardware on Machines and missing files get installed when hardware get installed

Comment: @jdweng, AlwaysLearning: Thank you guys. The issue turned out to be with the setup file. It was looking for a older version, while the squirrel was calling the latest version on the server. I had to update the setup file to be the latest version and it worked. Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: Why did it work for some users and not others?

Comment: for the users who got the app working they were having the older version of the app which was the same as the setup file. While the new users were trying to update with the version of the setup file, while Squirrel was seeing the new version available.